# inject html markup around random words in string using c#

Tags: c#, html, string

want to inject html markup around random words in string like

"this is a string for this question" the result should be like "this is a string <"legend title="xyz">for<"/legend> this question". i want to do it using c#. quotes are inserted to make markup appear

Comment: What do you mean by quotes inserted to make markup appear?

Answer (score 0):

For each legend you know, [replace](http://dotnetperls.com/replace) every occurence of the explained term with the corresponding HTML.